# What is the difference?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm learning now Angular and Angular Material. On the website of Angular Material there is an example how to build a table.

If I do it selfsame it's written, it won't work as well. It will be looking as I don't have half of css styles.
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

But if I change it to this, it will be looking already fine.

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

And I didn't yet get it, how I can use buttons with css styles. Maybe I've missed something.

Thank You!

Comment: in one use tr and a  "directive" to change the tr, in the other hand you has direcctly the "directive"

Comment: So. I don't need f.e. `<tr mat-... \tr>` If I don't want to change something in the styling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mat-table` renders table, so

```
<mat-table />
```

becomes

```
<table /> <-- material table
```

But `table mat-table` renders table, inside table

```
<table mat-table />
```

becomes

```
<table> <-- your parent element
  <table /> <-- material table
</table>
```

same for `th`, `tr`, ...etc

Comment: Why am I Iosing then by this way `<table mat-table>` styles?

Comment: because css styles and made for table, not for table inside table

Comment: I'm working on an app where someone wrote `<table mat-table ...>` and it's not rendered as 2 nested tables, it renders a single `<table>`.